# Trying to parse string from a website that gives device status with a value at the end

Tags: ruby

I'm using ruby and trying to get a value from a string that I received from an URI.PARSE.

Below is what I get back from the URI.PARSE and is in my string.  You can see it in the result at the bottom.  Q8:0;  I only need the Device which in this case is Q8 and the value is 0.  The device is always a string but sometimes the value is a string and sometimes a integer.  I want to be able to evaluate this result to do events based on the values.

```
html code>Q8:0;html code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_, device, value, _ = "html code>Q8:0;html code".split(/[>:;]/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I think I need to truncate the string down so that I can split it that way effectively. Right now there are way to many >: and other characters.   Any ideas?

Comment: That code was helpful once I got it truncated down.  Thank you.