# Truncate String from html string

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to truncate some data received from a URI:PARSE...it is full of html codes and data, The result at the end is what I need.

Here's the string (abbreviated) ' **junk**"Result">Q8:0;**junk**

What's is the best way to truncate the extra stuff in the string so that I can split the data I need into variables.

Thanks in advance,
Philip
pabbott@cpak.com

Comment: please post the entire string you need to update as well as what concretely you need to truncate. whitespaces? tabs? etc. what "junk" around your string means?

Comment: are you reposting your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554328/trying-to-parse-string-from-a-website-that-gives-device-status-with-a-value-at-t)?

Comment: I want to truncate it down to the string 'Result">Q8:0'.  The junk is just extra stuff in the current string before and after this string that I want.

Comment: ok, and how do we guess what junk you have around your string? is it literal "junk" can not you then simply `string.gsub(/\Ajunk|junk\Z/, '')`?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>

</title></head><body><form name="form1" method="post" action="tenHSServer.aspx?t=34&amp;f=DeviceValue&amp;d=R10" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTkzNDcxNzcwM2RkM4AHUDZdWZytDdspzLq7+FOXRfQ=" />
</div>

<span id="Result">R10:100;</span>
</form></body></html>

Comment: As you can see it's very long...I only need the result info the...R10:100

Comment: ok, and how do we guess what is the result here and what is not? if is always inside `<span id="Result">...</span>` i'll post an answer how to extract it

Comment: yes it is always inside that expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend to use `Nokogiri` to extract your value from `Result` span:

```
require 'nokogiri'

response = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>;
</title></head><body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="tenHSServer.aspx?t=34&amp;f=DeviceValue&amp;d=R10" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTkzNDcxNzcwM2RkM4AHUDZdWZytDdspzLq7+FOXRfQ=" />
</div>
<span id="Result">R10:100;</span>
</form></body>
</html>'

result = nil
if doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response) rescue nil
  if span = doc.css('#Result')
    result = span.text
  end
end

puts result
#=> R10:100;
```

however if you can not / do not want to install `Nokogiri`, use this regexp instead:

```
result = response.scan(/id=["|']Result["|']>([^<]*)<\//m).flatten.first
puts result
#=> R10:100;
```

Comment: really glad you sorted this out! please consider to mark it answered

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything up to and including `<span id=\"Result\">` with the first call to sub()
Then remove everything after and including `</span>` from what's left with the second call to sub()

Assume you store your html in the variable mystring

```
result = mystring.sub(/.*<span id=\"Result\">/,'').sub(/<\/span>.*/,'')
```

If you can't always rely on the elements being spans, you could use the following:

```
result = mystring.sub(/.*id=\"Result\">/,'').sub(/<\/.*/,'')
```

Comment: The first one only eliminates the spanid and not the preceding because of spacing I suppose.  The second one eliminates everything that is close to it but leaves the above lines....There is spacing between some of these lines that doesn't show up in my cut and paste to the site.  There is spacing or a return between the html line, the /title line and the <span line"  Any way to compensate for that?

Comment: ah ok, no worries. I just put your whole string in single quotes when I tested and that worked.